# Referencing sub-query in multiple conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I have a single table called `employees`:

```
id     |    name    |    born    |    stinky
-------------------------------------------------
1          Chris        1982            1
2          Chris        1982            1
3           Bob         1982            0
4          Chris        1982            1
```

I want to grab rows 2, 4 based on the following condition:

```sql
SELECT 
    id,name,born,stinky
FROM
    employees
WHERE
    name=(SELECT name FROM employees WHERE id=1)
        AND
    born=(SELECT born FROM employees WHERE id=1)
        AND
    stinky=(SELECT stinky FROM employees WHERE id=1)
        AND
    id != 1
```

Is there a way to optimize this to only execute one single sub-query, and then reference the sub-query data multiple times? For example, something like this:

```sql
SELECT 
    id,name,born,stinky
FROM
    employees
SUBQUERY
    (SELECT name FROM employees WHERE id=1) AS XX
WHERE
    name=XX.name
        AND
    born=XX.born
        AND
    stinky=XX.stinky
        AND
    id != 1
```

Comment: Look into JOIN operator

Comment: I'm familiar with `JOIN` but is that the correct way to do this? I've seen `CROSS APPLY`, `LATERAL`, etc...

Comment: @forpas Corrected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the subquery only once:

```
SELECT id,name,born,stinky
FROM employees
WHERE (name,born,stinky) = (SELECT name,born,stinky FROM employees WHERE id=1)
  AND id <> 1
```

Another way to do it is with a join:

```
SELECT e.id,e.name,e.born,e.stinky
FROM employees e
INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM employees WHERE id=1) t
ON (t.name,t.born,t.stinky) = (e.name,e.born,e.stinky) AND t.id <> e.id
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=dae60780dc67daa83f46e2ccaca93b6b).
Results:

| id | name | born | stinky |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | Chris | 1982 | 1 |
| 4 | Chris | 1982 | 1 |